# How to open and collapse the same JQuery accordion with click on it only

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, accordion

Trying to get the accordion open and collapse **only** when it's being clicked. I am able to open/collapse it but it is getting closed **also** when another accordion is clicked.

It should open or close on its own - independently from other accordions.

This is what I have tried.

JS:

```
$(document).on("click", ".accordion-toggle", function () {
        if ($(this).attr('class').indexOf('open') == -1)
   $(this).toggleClass("open").next().slideToggle('fast');
        //Hide the other panels
        $(".accordion-toggle").not($(this)).removeClass("open");
        $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
    });
```

Fiddle:
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8yap08dc/)

Comment: I didn't get the problem (`I am able to able but it is getting close when I select the other accordion`), but your fiddle works fine, except all accordions are open at start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have created a new fiddle with some css...

HTML

```
<div class="accordion-container">
    <a href="#" class="accordion-toggle">Heading 1</a>
    <div class="accordion-content">
        Content 1
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-container">
    <a href="#" class="accordion-toggle">Heading 2</a>
    <div class="accordion-content">
        Content 2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-container">
    <a href="#" class="accordion-toggle">Heading 3</a>
    <div class="accordion-content">
        Content 3
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        // create accordion variables
        var accordion = $(this);
        var accordionContent = accordion.next('.accordion-content');

        // toggle accordion link open class
        accordion.toggleClass("open");
        // toggle accordion content
        accordionContent.slideToggle(250);

    });
});
```

please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avnaveen91/8yap08dc/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Easy and simple bootstrap `accordion` on a click
HTML

```
    <button type="button" class="btn openpanel">Open panel 3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn closepanel">Close panel 3</button>
    <hr>
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
       <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel1">Panel 1</a>
            </h4>
         </div>
         <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Contents panel 1
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel2">Panel 2</a>
            </h4>
         </div>
         <div id="panel2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Contents panel 2
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel3">Panel 3</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Contents panel 3
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Simple js code

```
$(".openpanel").on("click", function() {
   $("#panel3").collapse('show');
});
$(".closepanel").on("click", function() {
   $("#panel3").collapse('hide');
});
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
   $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
});
```

I hope it will help you.